# Get permissions for a TeamDrive folder

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-drive-api, google-drive-shared-drive

I am trying to get the list of users of have access (Edit, Comment, View ...) for a TeamDrive Root Folder not a TeamDrive file.

First try :

```
var folders = Drive.Teamdrives.list({
  pageSize:100,
  pageToken:folderPT
});

for (var i = 0; i < folders.items.length; i++)
    {
      var folder = folders.items[i];

      var teamDrive = Drive.Teamdrives.get(folder.id);
      var test = DriveApp.getFolderById(folder.id);
      Logger.log(test.getEditors());
    }
```

With which methods I have to work ? Is it possible to do this ?

The response from my code is only empty results:

```
[18-09-05 14:18:36:282 CEST] []
[18-09-05 14:18:36:771 CEST] []
[18-09-05 14:18:37:143 CEST] []
[18-09-05 14:18:37:625 CEST] []
[18-09-05 14:18:38:306 CEST] []
[18-09-05 14:18:38:690 CEST] []
```

Edit : 
In fact the code above is working, my test folder was empty. 
But the answer below is better.

Comment: what is the issue with your code as it is?

Comment: do you have a list of users you want to check against? this would be possible by testing each user against the permissions on the Teamdrive.

Comment: @DaImTo , I will update my post the response is "[]"

Comment: @Jonathon I have a list of user that have access to the file in the TeamDrives. My goal is to compare those list and get users who have access to a file but who is external to the TheamDrive forlder . I hope it's understandable.

Comment: So users who a file is shared with who are not one the default members of the drive?

Comment: @Jonathon yes it's this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a file to determine the permissions set on the file itself or inherited from the Team Drive.

You can do this via the `Permissions` namespace within `Drive`.

```
function getFilePermissions(fileId) {

  var permissions = Drive.Permissions.list(fileId,  {supportsTeamDrives:true,
                                                     corpora: 'teamDrive',
                                                     includeTeamDriveItems: true})
  .items
  .reduce(function(all, i){

    var role = i.teamDrivePermissionDetails.map(function(permission){

      // commenters are flagged as having an additional role as readers
      var activeRole = (i.additionalRoles) ?  i.additionalRoles[0] : permission.role;

      return {emailAddress: i.emailAddress,
              teamDrivePermissionType: permission.teamDrivePermissionType,
              role: activeRole};
    });

    return all.concat(role);
  }, []);

  return permissions;
}
```

This function reduces the amount of information returned by the `Permissions.list` call to return an object array from which you can ascertain a whole bunch of information. A single user could be a reader of the Team Drive but a Writer (editor) of the file itself, this function returns both permissions.

e.g.

```
 [
    {
        "emailAddress": "geoff@example.com",
        "teamDrivePermissionType": "member",     <-- a Team Drive permission
        "role": "organizer"                      <-- an Team Drive domain member
    },
    {
        "emailAddress": "jonathon@example.com", 
        "teamDrivePermissionType": "member",
        "role": "writer"                         <-- a non-Domain member
    },
    {
        "emailAddress": "jonathon@example.com",
        "teamDrivePermissionType": "file",
        "role": "writer"                         <-- editor set on the file share
    },
    {
        "emailAddress": "svea@example.com",
        "teamDrivePermissionType": "file",
        "role": "reader"                         <-- viewing rights set at file level
    },
    {
        "emailAddress": "info@example.com",
        "teamDrivePermissionType": "member",
        "role": "organizer"
    },
    {
        "emailAddress": "rebekkah@example.com",
        "teamDrivePermissionType": "file",
        "role": "commenter"                      <-- this is a reader with comment rights
    }
]
```

Filter it by `member` or `file` (non-member), or by role: reader, writer, etc..

For more information on the Permissions object schema check here: [Permissions Resource](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions#resource)

Comment: I think your answer meet perfectly my need thank you. 
Where can I filter it by member or file ?

Comment: the parameter `teamDrivePermissionType`